# c++ HDD thrashing cause

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, x11

I'm working on a project that uses opencv to detect some images on screen and gets their coordinates. I found a function on stackoverflow that takes screenshots very fast so I can scan the screen very fast. Here is the code:

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;

//Function to take screenshots, this is the function that seems to be causing the HDD thrashing

void ImageFromDisplay(std::vector<uint8_t>& Pixels, int& Width, int& Height, int& BitsPerPixel)
{
    Display* display = XOpenDisplay(nullptr);
    Window root = DefaultRootWindow(display);

    XWindowAttributes attributes = {0};
    XGetWindowAttributes(display, root, &attributes);

    Width = attributes.width;
    Height = attributes.height;

    XImage* img = XGetImage(display, root, 0, 0 , Width, Height, AllPlanes, ZPixmap);
    BitsPerPixel = img->bits_per_pixel;
    Pixels.resize(Width * Height * 4);

    memcpy(&Pixels[0], img->data, Pixels.size());

    XFree(img);
    XCloseDisplay(display);
}

int main(){
    int Width = 0;
    int Height = 0;
    int Bpp = 0;
    std::vector<std::uint8_t> Pixels;

    while (1){
        //Func to take image (this is what is causing the thrashing)
        ImageFromDisplay(Pixels, Width, Height, Bpp);

        if (Width && Height){
            //Create a matrix
            Mat img = Mat(Height, Width, Bpp > 24 ? CV_8UC4 : CV_8UC3, &Pixels[0]);

            //Display matrix
            imshow("Display window", img);

            waitKey(1);
        }
    }
}
```

I have no experience with X11 so I have no idea how to fix this. Could anyone please tell me what exactly is causing the thrashing and how can I fix it?

Comment: For clarification, your HDD is broken = you can throw it away? It´s unlikely that your code is the reason.

Comment: It could be using swap

Comment: `Pixels.resize(Width * Height * 4);` <-- 4 must be a 3 in the BitsPerPixel==24 case (imho, your memcpy segfaults there)

Comment: but it just segfaults, right ? it does not 'destroy harddisks'  ? ;)

Comment: You should probably call `XDestroyImage(img);` instead of `XFree(img);` to prevent leaking the image memory. I'm also not very familiar with the X API but if you're going to loop over it, I don't think you should open and close the display connection all of the time for no reason. Oh, and like @berak said, the size should be calculated a little more carefully

Comment: Ya, Its using the swap. The program runs fine at the start, but after 30 seconds the program uses all the memory available and the HDD starts going crazy and the OS crashes. It doesnt segfault. And BTW I just bought a new HDD.

Comment: Sounds to me that you're leaking resources.

Comment: Well I just added a check for `BitsPerPixel==24` and used `XDestroyImage(img);` instead of `XFree(img);` It seems to be working now. A bit slow, but still working

Comment: @abc if you want it faster you should not, allocate, copy, deallocate in a loop. You should get the initial image, keep the connection open, update the image with `XGetSubImage` and if you're done clean up the one single `XImage *` and display connection.